# Save gensim Word2vec model in binary format .bin with save_word2vec_format

Tags: python, attributes, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I'm training my own word2vec model using different data. To implement the resulting model into my classifier and compare the results with the original pre-trained Word2vec model I need to save the model in binary extension .bin. Here is my code, *sentences* is a list of short messages.

```
import gensim, logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
sentences = gensim.models.word2vec.LineSentence('dati.txt')
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(
sentences, size=300, window=5, min_count=5, workers=5,
sg=1, hs=1, negative=0
)
model.save_word2vec_format('model.bin', binary=True)
```

The last method, save_word2vec_format, gives me this error:

`AttributeError: 'Word2Vec' object has no attribute 'save_word2vec_format'`

What am I missing here? I've read the documentation of gensim and other forums. This [repo on github](https://github.com/devmount/GermanWordEmbeddings/blob/c2b603a07d968146995ee9dde54a25fd0aa8586a/training.py#L56) uses almost the same configuration so I cannot understand what's wrong. I've tried to switch from skipgram to cbow and from hierarchical softmax to negative sampling with no results.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using a pre-release release candidate version of gensim, or code directly from the `develop` branch?

In those versions `save_word2vec_format()` has moved to a utility class called `KeyedVectors`.

You won't yet (as of February 2017) get these versions from the usual way of installing gensim, `pip install gensim` – and it's likely that by the time this change is in the official distribution, the error message for trying the older call will be improved.

I recommend using the version that comes via plain `pip install gensim` unless you are a relatively expert user who is also carefully following the project [CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md).

Comment: Thank you for your crystal clear reply. I thought it might be a problem about the gensim version as I wasn't seeing any method called save_word2vec_format among those attached to model. I've installed gensim through easy_install -U gensim as I read on the website documentation. I've unistalled gensim and used plain pip install and now it works smoothly. Thank you very much!

Comment: FYI I think 1.0.0 is now official, so even `pip install gensim` will get a version with the API change, but I also think the error message has been improved (to point people at using `KeyedVectors` instead).

Answer (score 8):

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec, KeyedVectors   
model.wv.save_word2vec_format('model.bin', binary=True)
```